# Что нужно знать хакеру?

Tags: взлом

Что нужно знать, чтобы вытворить такое: [YouTube: Хакеры веселятся](http://youtube.com/watch?v=Ezi_sZpl5PY)?
А именно, какие технологии, уровни OSI и т.п. нужно хорошо знать?

Comment: практически все, что связано с электроникой  
+английский

Comment: https://kali.training/downloads/Kali-Linux-Revealed-1st-edition.pdf

Answer (score 34, accepted):

- Первое - бегать. Хорошо бегать, потому что как догонят, хорошо дадут.
- Второе - нужно разбираться в том, что теперь модно называть "умный дом" - когда свет, тепло и другие коммуникации управляются централизовано. 
  Понятно, что если свет включается только обычным включателем, то будь в десятом колене потомственным "хакером" - ничего не получится. Поэтому, очень хорошо изучить электронику и электротехнику, хотя бы на базовом уровне факультета типа РТФ. Уметь держать в руках паяльник - приветствуется.
- Третье - английский. Просто очень много литературы на нем и с ним будет заметно проще.
- Четвертое, учитывая последние тенденции - и китайский (что бы читать доки в оригинале).
- Пятое - тетрис/стрелялку уметь написать, потом вывести на экран уже не штука. Но уметь нужно. Желательно изучить с++/ассемблер. Другими языками брезговать также не стоит.
- И напоследок - куча свободного времени, желание учится и не сдаватся и немного везения.

Comment: по поводу бегать это да)))

Comment: И еще нужен хороший адвокат.

Comment: >И еще нужен хороший адвокат.
Это если поймают.
А по ролику - "фейк" чистой воды. На западе лампочки, как правило, энергосберегающие, с большим запаздыванием на включение. В `galaxy` на такой скорости не поиграешь, да и яркость везде одинаковая :)

Answer (score 17):

Думаю, что для такого нужно знать хорошо программы для видео монтажа. Что у нас там сейчас самое популярное, Adobe Premiere, Sony Vegas? Потому что даже человек с базовыми знаниями физики, электротехники, логики поймет, что это монтаж и компьютерная графика. Перечислять все недочеты смысла не имеет, но картинка действительно выглядит далекой от жизни.

По поводу того, как можно взломать реальный умный дом, то могу процитировать моего преподавателя, который однажды сказал: "Если хотите научиться взламывать систему, вначале научитесь её защищать". В остальном, думаю другие посты уже раскрыли тему.

Comment: Ясно, что монтаж. Но дело даже не в этом.

Comment: это чтобы защитить, надо знать, как сломать. Не путайте порядок. Если вы видели копья и луки, вы не поставите стену от танка.

Comment: @Sh4dow, могу поспорить. Танк - это в одно время, и следствие того, что стена от копей и луков, и причина тому, что теперь стена будет еще и от танка. С другой стороны, когда защита есть от всего, нужно найти то, от чего еще защиты нет. Так что вы оба в чем-то правы.

Comment: Если посмотреть чуть шире компов, станет очевидно, что оружие появилось раньше, чем защита) Ну и вообще логика странная - чтобы ударить кого-нибудь кувалдой, совершенно не обязательно знать способы защиты. А вот наоборот - таки обязательно.

Answer (score 6):

Самый главный совет для хакера - новичка -> хакнуть ресурс со своего домашнего компа. Начинайте экспериментировать, потом поделитесь впечатлениями.

Comment: А за что минус? Обоснуйте пожалуйста.

Comment: А Вы бы хотели, чтобы хакнули Ваш ресурс?

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, я просто хотел, что-бы господин Егоров просто вначале собрал соответствующую информация, а потом уже задавал откровенно глупые вопросы.

Comment: Если вопрос чисто теоретический, то это нормально. Но боюсь, что неокрепшие юношеские мозги могут такого насмотревшись на всякую дурь отважиться

Comment: Полностью согласен.

Comment: Вячеслав Кириченко , на самом деле я просто не правильно задал вопрос у меня не было и в мыслях что б повторить это , мне просто понравилась идея и я захотел узнать как это все работает(а из за отсутствия базы знаний об этом я не смог прогуглить для дальнейшего изучения) , а то я кроме веб-программирования ни чего не знаю  . И это гораздо интереснее чем внедрять в сайты sql инъекции да воровать куки находя xss уязвимости .А ожидал я примерно такого ответа : начать с изучения радиоэллектроники (так мне посоветовал препод).

Comment: так что вопрос был чисто теоретический

Comment: Если серьезно, я думаю, такое сделать нереально

Comment: Ну и молодец. Только НИКОГДА НЕ ЛЕЗЬ В ЧУЖОЙ КОМП С КОМПА, ПО КОТОРОМУ тебя банально могут вычислить :) Удачи.

Comment: спаасибо .

Answer (score 4):

Хм, почему за столько лет никто даже не упомянул, что одним из самых важных элементов( *если уж и не самым важным* ) является **команда**, единомышленники, люди, разделяющие интересы и одержимые общей идеей. Ведь от общения и ощущения своей целостности с ними и приходит тот самый энтузиазм, истинный хакерский дух, в которых заключена сила ;)

---

**P.S** И пускай видео - всего лишь подделка, зато через него можно явно видеть, как важна командная работа.

Answer (score 3):

Как стать хакером?

Стать хакером очень просто!

Достаточно выучить и понять: математические дисциплины (математический анализ, теория функций комплексного переменного, алгебра, геометрия, теория вероятностей, математическая статистика, математическая логика и дискретная математика), инженерные дисциплины (физика, аппаратные средства вычислительной техники, основы радиоэлектроники, сети связи и защита информации от технической разведки), дисциплины по программированию и вычислительной технике (информатика, языки программирования высокого уровня, методы программирования, язык ассемблера, операционные системы, СУБД и вычислительные сети), специальные дисциплины (криптография, и теоретические основы защиты компьютерных систем).

Это достаточно полный список. Но если вы хотите стать не простым хакером, а настоящим специалистом своего дела, то необходимо также знать:

- криптографические методы в системах защиты государственной, конфиденциальной и коммерческой информации;
- криптографические методы в системах защиты и дешифрования информации;
- математические модели процессов, возникающих при защите информации;
- методы решения вероятностных, статистических и алгоритмических задач криптографического анализа, синтеза шифросистем и криптографических протоколов;
- методы построения математических моделей защищаемой информации, шифров и шифросистем;
- методы преобразования информации в сетях различного типа;
- обеспечение надежности функционирования аппаратуры шифрования и тестирования программно-аппаратных реализаций криптографических алгоритмов;
- общая методология криптографического анализа и построения оценок криптографической стойкости шифросистем;
- определение каналов утечки информации методом измерения и расчета параметров опасных сигналов;
- основные положения теории электрических цепей;
- основные принципы организации систем и сетей связи, особенности современных сетевых архитектур;
- основные типы шифров, шифросистем, криптографических протоколов и систем защиты;
- особенности разработки и сопровождения ПО для рабочих групп и парапрограммирование.

(с)Б.Лаврентьев ( COMPUTERWORLD/КИЕВ )

Answer (score 2):

Знать основы асемблера, и уметь не палить железо при помощи асемблера, а дальше оно само собой все будет делаться

Comment: А еще Уголовный Кодекс. :) Причем желательно сразу нескольких стран (о существовании которых вы случайно узнали)Но в общем - ерунда. Такие ролики можно делать пачками. Смешно, главное всерьез это не воспринимать и ... не пытаться повторить в реале :)